# Access Jade table values in Node.JS

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, pug

```
table(class= "table-striped table-striped table-hover")
        thead
                th  
                 h2 #{movie.title}

        tbody

                tr

                    td
                        b Tagline : #{movie.tag} 
                        br
                        b Rating :  #{movie.rating}
                        br
                        b Synopsis :
                        p #{movie.overview}
                        b Available Copies : #{movie.copies}
                        br
                        input.btn-danger.btn-sm(type="submit", value="Buy")  

                    td
                         img(src= movie.poster width="250" height="300")
                         p
                            a.btn.btn-info(href='http://www.imdb.com/title/'+movie.movie_id)  Watch Trailer &raquo;
```

`#{ }` values are coming from Mysql table.**After I submit this page** ,I want to reuse `#{movie.title}` `#{movie.tag}` 
in Node.js console. For example, I would like to do `console.log(movie.title)`
How do I do that?Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm assuming you have a Node.js app rendering this file? If so, can't you simply log the data before/after rendering?

Comment: How do I log the data after I submit the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This might not be an efficient way.Tried using `global` object.

```
 global.movieName = rows[0].title;
 global.movieRating = rows[0].rating;
```

Answer (score 1):

Submit with jquery, and add the `#{movie.title}` and `#{movie.tag}` to a variable to the post, somelike this..

**Button:**

```
<input type='button' value='Submit form' onClick='submitDetailsForm()' />
```

**JS:**

```
   <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var title = !{
        JSON.stringify(movie.title)
    };
    var tag = !{
        JSON.stringify(movie.tag)
    };
    var data = {
        title: title,
        tag: tag
    };

    function submitDetailsForm() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            cache: false,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            url: '/send',
            success: function(retorno) {

            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

**Node.js:**

```
app.post('/send', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.title);
    console.log(req.tag);
});
```